# how can I make my textbox capture characters why textbox does not capture input

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

when I put a breakpoints on my `textbox` it shows `textbox.length = ""` even if there are characters in the textbox

Comment: Can you share the relevant bits of your code?

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'breakpoint on a TextBox'.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Length` property present in [`TextBox Class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Probably you mean to Check the `Length` on Textbox `Text` property which is of `string` type.

```
textbox.Text.Length
```

Answer (score 0):

More info about the code would be nice. Is your Textbox really enabled? No transparent layer in front of it? You used the mySQL-Tag. Does that mean you use some kind of binding in textbox? Possibly you can't change the content of your textbox, because the database-binding / connection is read-only?

Is there really some textbox.length property?? Are you sure you are referring to the right property? Try this:

```
Convert.ToString(textBox1.TextLength)
```

Comment: yes there is a .length function to calculate length of characters in textbox and no you cant put a break point on a text but u can certainly insert one in the code behind and see what is being returned @TaW in future learn to read the question before placing ur hands on the keyboard